# Go lang slice of interface

Tags: go, iteration, slice

I am trying to iterate over a slice of interfaces to find my specific struct by id and change the attribute.

```
type A struct {
    ID    ID
    Steps []Step
}

type Step interface{}

type B struct {
    ID       ID
}

type C struct {
   ID     ID
}

func (s *A) findStepByID(id ID) (Step, error) {
    for index, step := range s.Steps {
        switch stepType := step.(type) {
        case A:
            if stepType.ID == id {
                return step, nil
            }
        case B:
            if stepType.ID == id {
                return step, nil
            }
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("no step found")
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("no step found")
}
```

When I found my struct for example `B` then I will set `B.ID = xy`

Comment: What is the concern here ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to do that i get the error that Step is an interface with no methods

Comment: The way with the interface method works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `findStepByID` returns an `interface{}` .If you want to assign ID with a new value you have to explicitly cast it to a type

Here assuming you use case as is to update the result and use updated value.There are two ways you may do it

1. Instead of a empty interface`interface{}` use a interface with function `UpdateID(ID)` defined
2. Use a type switch and inside switch only do the update

I would not suggest second one as it has scope problems